# Regular expression to split words with accented characters from latin

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm working on a html tool to study ancient latin language. 
There is one exercise where student have to click on some single word, 
in which there is a `div` with a piece of latin:

```
<div class="clickable">
                   Cum a Romanis copiis vincĭtur măr, Gallia terra fera est. 
Regionis incŏlae terram non colunt, autem sagittis feras necant et postea eas vorant. 
Etiam a_femĭnis vita agrestis agĭtur, 
miseras vestes induunt et cum familiā in parvis casis vivunt. 
Vita secūra nimiaeque divitiae a Gallis contemnuntur. 
Gallorum civitates acrĭter pugnant et ab inimicis copiis timentur. 
Galli densis silvis defenduntur, tamen Roma feram Galliam capit. 
</div>
```

In my javascript I wrap all single words into a `<span>` with a regex, and I apply some actions.

```
 var words = $('div.clickable');        
    words.html(function(index, oldHtml) {
        var myText = oldHtml.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>')

        return myText;
    }).click(function(event) { 
        if(!$(event.target).hasClass("word"))return; 
        alert($(event.target).text());
    }
```

The problem is that the words that contains `ĭ, ŏ, ā`, are not wrapped correctly, but are divided in correspondence of these characters.

How I can match correctly this class of words?

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s568c0pp/1/)**

Comment: Try using [XRegExp](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/160386) for more suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split your text by divider. In common case it may be space or different punctuation marks:

```
(.+?)([\s,.!?;:)([\]]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/xW4pF1/5

**Edit**

```
var words = $('div.clickable');        
words.html(function(index, oldHtml) {
    var myText = oldHtml.replace(/(.+?)([\s,.!?;:)([\]]+)/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>$2')

    return myText;
}).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).hasClass("word"))return; 
    alert($(event.target).text());
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s568c0pp/3/

Comment: This approach works fine, but match also the dividers, how to exclude punctations from result?

Comment: It matches 2 groups: word and divider. So in your replace function use both in replacement: `oldHtml.replace(/(.+?)([\s\,\.\!\?]+)/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>$2')` https://jsfiddle.net/s568c0pp/2/

Answer (score 1):

The `\w` meta character is used to find a word character from `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, including the `_` (underscore) character.
So you need to change your regex to use the range of Unicode symbols instead of `\w`.

You also can try `\p{L}` instead of `\w` to match any Unicode character.

See also: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: I have tried with /\b(\p{L}+?)\b/g but doesn't match any word.

Comment: Sorry, JavaScript regex engine is little bit different.
Give me couple of minutes... I'll check the alternative.